# Get sum without group by but with subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, subquery

i have two tables for example:

```
BALANCE             VS
╔══════╦══════╗     ╔══════╦═══════╗
║ V_ID ║ BAL  ║     ║ V_ID ║ NAME  ║
╠══════╬══════╣     ╠══════╬═══════╣
║    1 ║ 1000 ║     ║    1 ║ Carl  ║
║    1 ║  500 ║     ║    2 ║ Peter ║
║    1 ║ -200 ║     ╚══════╩═══════╝
║    2 ║  350 ║     
║    2 ║ 1000 ║     
╚══════╩══════╝
```

Now i've done a query like:

```
select 
    NAME,sum(BAL)
from VS,BALANCE
where VS.V_ID = BALANCE.V_ID
group by NAME
```

And the result is:

```
╔═══════╦══════╗
║ NAME  ║ BAL  ║
╠═══════╬══════╣
║ Carl  ║ 1300 ║
║ Peter ║ 1350 ║
╚═══════╩══════╝
```

But i'd like to know how its done **without** the ´group by´ clause. Something like a subquery.
I tried different things but i cant figure out how it would work. I always end with results like all the values summed up into one row or results like the above one but without grouping.

may be anyone could help me

greetings

edit:forgot sum()

Comment: are u sure your query gives the result as you shown, since there is no sum() in the query.

Comment: Just curious, why on earth do you want to avoid group by clause?

Comment: Without SUM it will bring back the BAL from one of the rows that matches the NAME (ie, the group by field). Which value of BAL it returns is underfined.

Comment: oh, i made a mistake in c/p. you are right. sum is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your current SQL to work using GROUP BY you would need the following (ie the SUM aggregate function):-

```
select     NAME, SUM(BAL)
from VS, BALANCE 
WHERE VS.V_ID = BALANCE.V_ID
group by NAME
```

Note that this is just your original SQL minimally modified to work and it still uses the implicit join you coded. Implicit joins should generally be avoided and better to use explicit INNER JOIN....ON syntax:-

```
select NAME, SUM(BAL)
from VS
INNER JOIN BALANCE 
ON VS.V_ID = BALANCE.V_ID
group by NAME
```

If you really want to avoid the GROUP BY then it is possible using a sub query, but is likely to be slower (as it effectively has to perform an extra query for every row tha main query returns):-

```
select NAME, (SELECT SUM(BAL) FROM BALANCE WHERE BALANCE.V_ID = VS.V_ID)
from VS
```

EDIT, in response to your comment on sub queries.

Correlated sub queries effectively force MySQL to get a result set, and then for each row on the result set to perform another query. Most of the time they are used to get an aggregate value (such as the max value of a field related to a row on the returned row, but where GROUP BY on the main query would not be viable).

For example if you had a list of comments for a user, but on each row you wanted to know the date of the latest comment from that user you might do the following:-

```
SELECT users.user_name, comments.comment_date, (SELECT MAX(comment_date) FROM comments WHERE comments.user_id = users.id) AS latest_comment_date
FROM users
INNER JOIN comments
ON users.id = comments.user_id
```

This could be written to do a non correlated sub query using GROUP BY which is then joined:-

```
SELECT users.user_name, comments.comment_date, latest_comment_date
FROM users
INNER JOIN comments
ON users.id = comments.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(comment_date) AS latest_comment_date
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY user_id
) sub1
ON users.id = sub1.user_id
```

If you are dealing with a large number of records on users this would likely be faster.

However if you were only dealing with a tiny number of records on users (and determining that number was quite complex), getting ALL the max comment dates would be an unnecessary overhead, and it forces a join against a sub query which isn't likely to use indexes.

Comment: Can't say I blame you, but that join was left as it was just to show the fix to his existing SQL to make it work. Added a comment to make this clearer

Comment: It works, but correlated sub queries like that (ie, a sub query which has a condition which relies on the main query) are generally not a good idea.

Comment: @fancyPants - it is not code I would use, but for the purpose it was posted (just to point out the missing SUM) modifying it to use explicit joins would just disguise the point I was making. It was obviously not intended as the solution (given they specifically wanted it to not use GROUP BY). For this reason I have removed your edit.

Comment: Wow, thanks men for the fast help. Of course i would always prefer the group by clause, but for this one i try to get more into subqueries and try to get all the different possibilities. if they are good or not. thanks a lot. and thanks too for the use of joins instead of implicit joins over where.

Comment: I have added some comments on using correlated sub queries and joining against sub queries.

Answer (score -1):

Try joining tables:

```
select NAME,BAL from VS JOIN BALANCE ON VS.V_ID = BALANCE.V_ID
```

Will return

```
NAME  |  BAL
-------------
 Carl |  1000
 Carl |  500
 Carl |  -200
 Peter|  350
 Peter|  1000
```

To get sum of BAL, you have to use GROUP BY, otherwise you will get SUM of all rows

Comment: You should sum all the balances and the name column should be unique.

Comment: its the other way to do it without a where clause, if you add group by NAME you get the same result as i do. but how you would do it without group by

Comment: @Daniel Why you can't use Group By?

Comment: @Justinas I could but i'd like to know how it'll function without. Just for my own interest.